# Using a sorting function for numerical sorting

Tags: sorting

Suppose I have an "oracle" which sorts as follows:

> > 1, 3, 2000, 11, 17, 20

Becomes

> > 1, 11, 17, 20, 2000, 3

(I don't what this mechanism is called). This is akin to UNIX's `sort` command (without the `-n`).

[I remember Windows used to sort filenames like this prior to Windows XP](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-numerical-file-name-sorting-and-enable-classic-literal-sorting-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7-explorer/)

---

Now, I have a bunch of numbers and this `sort` oracle and I want to sort the numbers numerically, how can I pre-process the numbers such that the `sort` oracle returns the correct order.

So, is there a function `f()` which takes in these numbers such that

> > sort f([1,3,2000,11,17,20])

would return the correct order.

The problem is, we need to sort a bunch of numbers numerically on a system where the only sort available is the sort procedure I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [lexicographical sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). You can pad the numbers with `0`s so they all have the same number of digits to get it to behave like a numerical sort. For instance, use a `%04d` format code with printf.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the numbers using this "oracle" sort function, resulting in a list of numbers called e.g.: `L`.
2. Remove all single-digit numbers from `L`, resulting in a list of numbers `L1`, and create a new list of numbers with the single-digit numbers in the same order as they were in `L`, resulting in a list of numbers `S` (if there are no single digit numbers in `L`, `S` is going to be empty).
3. Remove all double-digit numbers from `L1`, resulting in a list of numbers `L2`, and append the double-digit numbers in the same order they were in `L1` to `S` (if there are no double-digit numbers in `L`, `L1` remains the same as `L` and no number is appended to `S`).
4. ...
5. Remove all n-digit numbers from `Ln-1`, resulting in an empty list of numbers, and append the n-digit numbers in the same order they were in `Ln-1` to `S`.
6. Now `S` contains the numerically sorted list of numbers, using only the "oracle" sort function and a function that returns the number of digits of a number, which hopefully your system has.

Of course, you do not need to create a new list of numbers `Lk` as you remove all k-digit numbers from `Lk-1` if the "oracle" sorted list `L` is mutable.